# Which formula is it to extract data from one dataset to another in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im pretty new to excel. And i would like to know which formula is it to extract data from one dataset to another. I have the raw data, but the next step is to clean up. For example, one column from dataset 1 --> sheet 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean exactly.
Do you mean that you want to draw data from another sheet with dynamic sheet name?
You may use function indirect then like:

```
= indirect("'sheet'!A1")
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Yes, i mean to draw some data points from one sheet to another to clean up. The final output here will be to make an average calculation for 2023, based on previous year numbers. So i need to clean the data and make the calculation. The problem i have is that i get #NAME? when i try to add something on a new sheet using formulas. But i am not so good with it.